# Display column name from the select SQL query and add it in the group by clause of same SQL query in nodejs

Tags: mysql, node.js

Below is the sql query. I want in some regular expr to fetch the column name from the sql query. Then add those column names in the group by clause of the same query.

```
SELECT  
        b.building_id,
        b.building_name,
        b.street_number,
        b.street_name, 
        ARRAY(b.floor_id)floor_ids 
      FROM 
        building b 
  
      WHERE
        b.monitored_status = 'monitored'
      GROUP BY 
        b.building_id
```

Comment: There is no `ARRAY()` function in MySQL.

Comment: Its in alasql. You can ignore that.

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is never appropriate. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I have arregation in my query with works for alasql. I just want the code to fetech the columns names and add in group by clause.